# Geostrophic adjustment with shallow water equations

Tags: oceanography, waves, fluid-dynamics

[image]

The linearized f-plane shallow water equations are:

```
$du'/dt - fv' = -g(d eta'/dx)$
dv'/dt + fu' = -g(d eta'/dy)
(d eta'/dt) + H((du'/dx)+(dv'/dy)) = 0
```

where g is gravitational acceleration, f is the Coriolis parameter, eta is sea surface height, H is depth, u and v are the horizontal components of velocity, and primes denote linearized variables. I am very lost on how to even begin the problem in the image. Do I need to plug in the equation eta = eta(k,l)*e^i(kx+ly) dkdl to the linearized equations and then calculate the geostrophic adjustment?

My understanding of Fourier coefficients is very loose and both my teacher's notes and my textbook are lacking in the math necessary to solve these equations.